# socket.io get socket inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, web-deployment

I'm using socket.io for node.js. If you add an event handler like this:

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect',function(socket){
    socket.on('some event',function(arg1,arg2){
       /// using socket to emit events for example
    }
}
```

Then I can access socket inside the callback for the 'some event'
However what if I use it like this

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect',function){
    socket.on('some event',myfunction);
}

function myFunction(arg1,arg2)
{
    //I want to use calling socket here.
}
```

How do I access socket in the later case?
I need  the socket to get the socket.id so I can know who called this event.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Well, if I understand what you want to do, you can simply:

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect',function){
    socket.on('some event',myfunction);
}

function myFunction(arg1,arg2)
{
    var socketId = this.id; //here you go, you can refer the socket with "this"
}
```

This is what I usually do to keep the code clean:

```
var on_potato = function(potatoData){

     var socket = this;
     var id = socket.id;

     //use potatoData and socket here
};

var on_tomato = function(tomatoData){

     var socket = this;
     var id = socket.id;

     //use tomatoData and socket here
};

var handleClientConnection = function (client) {

    client.on('potato', on_potato);
    client.on('tomato', on_tomato);
};

io.on('connection', handleClientConnection)
```

Comment: one part is missing from answer how to use id to get socket back

Comment: oh wait nvm this is the socket

Comment: best answer here

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so after discussing this a potential solution is to just invoke your named function from within the anoymous callback function passed to the `on` method.

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){

 socket.on('someEvent', function(username, date){

    // If you emitted an object, you'll need to parse the incoming data. So say
    // You emitted {username: 'SomeName', date: 'SomeDate' }
    // You could just pass data.username and data.date directly
    // or put them into local variables, like:
    //var username = data.username, date = data.date;

    // Invoke your named function here and you can pass 
    // whatever you want to it, along with the socket
    myFunction(username, date, socket)
  })
})

myFunction(username, date, socket){
 // Do whatever you're doing with the passed paramaters
}
```

Comment: Minor tweak, but I don't think the socket is passed into the anonymous function; if you remove it, then it will use the `socket` variable from the scope above rather than whatever is passed in there.

Comment: It's not working. username and  date are undefined in the socket.on('someEvent', function(){... They are passed from the client page to the server. And obviously getting a complication error

Comment: Are they being passed through `socket.emit` or what? The caveat here is that the additional parameters need to be available within an accessible scope.

Comment: Yes. that's the whole idea. The user of the library on the server side can pass custom events and calbacks, and send those events with arguments from the client web page.

Comment: Then you add those as paramters to the passed anonymous function (updated my post) and then they'll get passed the secondary named function in turn.

Comment: I believe `socket.io` passes a single object when emitting data, so you'll have to parse out the parameters and pass them from there.

Comment: socket.io allows you to pass as many parameters as you want. your answer works, if I set the number of parameters fixed.

Comment: Cool! Yeah, either works in socket.io. Glad to here it works.

Comment: That will do. Please feel free to upvote the question because I bet it will come up as an issue for others as well. Thank you guys.

Comment: Make sure to mark as solved so it can be referred as a resolved question for duplicates too!

Answer (score 1):

I've used Lodash's [partial](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) function quite often to solve problems like this ([Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) has one as well, which does the same thing). Basically what it does is create a new function that has some of the original function's arguments filled in. So what you would do is something like this:

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
  socket.on('some event', _.partial(myfunction, socket));
});

function myFunction(socket, ...args) {
  // whatever you wanna do
}
```

Then, when the new [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Currying) function is returned from the partial execution, it has `socket` prefilled as the first param and you can use it how you'd like.

Just a note that the `...args` is just a placeholder for whatever you want to put there. Also, I'm not sure if socket.io passes anything into the function on firing the callback, which may affect the placement of the arguments into the curried function. If socket, shouldn't be the first argument, you can make it the second thusly:

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect', function(socket)){
  socket.on('some event', _.partial(myfunction, _, socket));
}

function myFunction(arg1, socket, ...args) {
  // whatever you wanna do
}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, it would be helpful to explain why. Unless you're being petty because I pointed out your answer doesn't work.

Comment: `_.partial` is going to be invoked at least once before the socket object is passed to the `connect` event, meaning `socket` will cause the function to throw an `undefined` error and the program will not start.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from the copy-paste from OP. The socket object is passed in from the function the event binding is called on.

Comment: partial is executed after io emits the 'connect' event, before socket emits the 'some event' event. OP, this should work, I've used this technique before.

Comment: No, `_.partial(myFunction, socket)` is going to be invoked even before the event is triggered since its a function invocation. It will throw an error since `socket` is not defined at all.

Comment: No, it won't. `_.partial(myFunction, socket)` is invoked at the time the callback fires, which is passed in to the `on` function and fires after that event is triggered. OP, please test this answer, this should work.

Comment: Try it yourself. Here's a quick example: https://gist.github.com/Aweary/cf1451e83fdf24f9e8d1. It uses an HTTP server which is an `EventEmitter` just like the `socket` is.

Comment: That is not analogous. This fork is analogous: https://gist.github.com/mAAdhaTTah/ab7dbca408e58146a7ca